# Area of two polar regions

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, polar-coordinates

I'm trying to find the region inside r=sinθ and outside r=1+cosθ. My issue is my limits of integration. I get an intersection at $\frac π2$ and one at the pole. What are my limits for the integral? sinθ will intersect the pole at 0 or π but 1+cosθ only intersects the pole at π. From looking at the graph this is  integral I came up with:

$$\frac12\int_{\frac π2}^π(sinθ)^2-(1+cosθ)^2dθ$$
Is this correct?

This is the picture:
[image]

How do I deal with intersections occurring at different angles?

**Edit:** New picture, the red region is what I'm looking for.[image]

Comment: Your integral looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

For $\pi /2 \leq \theta \leq \pi$, which is the region you want, the function $r = F(\theta) = \sin \theta$ is your “outer” function, and $r = g(\theta) = 1 + \cos \theta$ is your “inner” function. Here, you have two options: you can integrate $F(\theta)-g(\theta)$ in one motion, as you have done, or you can find the areas bounded by $F(\theta)$ and $g(\theta)$ and subtract them. Either way, they perfectly equivalent.

You will want to use the polar area formula $A = \frac{1}{2} \int_\alpha^\beta r^2 \, d\theta$ for each curve:

$$\begin{align}
A &= \frac{1}{2} \int_\alpha^\beta \left( F^2- g^2 \right) \, d\theta \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi} \left[ (\sin\theta)^2 - (1 + \cos\theta)^2 \right] \, d\theta
\end{align}$$

A quick check with the [calculator](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=antiderivative%20of%20(sin%20x)%5E2%20-%20(1%20%2B%20cos%20x)%5E2) tells me this would reduce to $$\ \left[ -\theta - 2\sin(\theta) - \sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)\right]_{\pi/2}^\pi$$
so I am going to make an educated guess and say that this was a with-calculator problem.

So, to conclude, your integral was spot on!